# Issue in sending mail simultaneously in android vial Gmail Client

Tags: android, gmail

I am using the below code to sending the email from my application

```
  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  i.setType("text/plain");
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"recipient@example.com"});
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
  i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body of email");
 try {
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
  Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
}
```

This code is sending my mail successfully for the first time. But when i send 2 mails simultaneously it sends only 1 mail.

Looking for some solution.

Comment: What do you mean by sending 2 mails simultaneously?

Comment: how do you send two emails simultaneously?

Comment: Do you mean multiple recipients?

Comment: I have a button share to send the mail. When i click the share the button then a intent chooser dialog appear. i select the Gmail app to send the mail. Then again i click the share button and again use Gmail  app to send the mail. But i received only the 1st mail.

Comment: if it is the same email?  If so this is probably a feature of gmail.  Also, have the first action completed before the second is fired?

Comment: yes, both are same email...OK i am checking the same

Comment: I guess you are sending second email while the first email is in the process of sending. Let first email be sent and then try again, I mean have some time gap before sending second email. Try this way, and tell me what is the result.

Comment: i have also tried the same. Now i am sending the second email when i received the 1st email. I have checked with my Yahoo account and found that it is working fine and we are receiving both mails. I think this is the feature of Gmail. Now my question is that how to avoid this or uncheck this feature in Gmail.